# I need to show the user specific data to the particular user after log in by that user it should show the its own information

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have created login page of groceryList  after login by particular user I need to display its own added grocery Item instead of added by other user I have used Angular js for front end ,Nodejs for handling the mongoose connection with mongodb .
Mongodb is having one collection with two document  1>users  2>groceries.

1>users  :contains user information means username,password.
2>groceries:Contains  groceries added by user

now my question is I need to show the added grocery by user1 it should not visible to user2 if he has not added . on which way I can implement this
data should be user specific please help me on this .
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: On groceries document, why don't you add 'user_id' of logged-in user as well. Then all you need to do is write a mongo find queries with user id equals user id to logged in user.

Comment: Thank you Ritesh I could Implement what u told now  now I am able to display respective data ,but now i am getting problem "suppose user1 add Mango   user1_id is assigned with mango  ,now user2 may also add Mango now the problem is user2_id will be assigned to it" how to deal with this situation ?

Comment: Create another record in mongodb with user2_id and mango details. I think currently you are replacing id of item. dont do that.